# How to add class for second and third level <li>

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 levels in the menu: Top - Second level - Third level. For the first level **li**, I added classes with this code:

```
//This function is responsible for adding class to parent menu item's
function add_menu_parent_class($items)
{
    $parents = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        //Check if the item is a parent item
        if ($item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent > 0) {
            $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
        }
    }

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (in_array($item->ID, $parents)) {
            //Add class to parents
            $item->classes[] = 'menu-item__parent';
        }
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_parent_class');
```

Now I need to add a separate class for the second level **li** and a separate class for the third level **li**. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if the argument have child then add your class for those childs

```
if ( $args->has_children ) {
    //trait to add class 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And how can I add by levels, separately for the second and third?

Comment: Check this answer here the: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914063/how-do-i-get-to-the-third-level-of-nested-children-in-this-php-array